# WPF TabControl - IDictionary missing key attribute error

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl on my grid and everything works fine, but the system complains that a key attribute is missing. The code compiles and works though. I have tried to add an x:Key property to the style but then it didn't work anymore. Any ideas?

```
<TabControl x:Name="mainTabControl" BorderBrush="White">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Grid Name="Panel">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="30,20"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Production">
            <Grid/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by - The code compiles and works, but the system complains that a key attribute is missing. Do you get this as a warning in Error List window of Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't get what's wrong. I get this as an error in the Errors list window in Visual Studio. An the code still compiles. The error is: "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a warning. You can make it go away by adding

```
x:Key="{x:Type TabPanel}"
```

Or you can suppress the warning if you don't want to add a Key attribute

In Solution Explorer, choose the project in which you want to suppress warnings.
On the menu bar, choose View, Property Pages.
Choose the Build page.
In the Suppress warnings box, specify the error codes of the warnings that you want to suppress, separated by semicolons, and then rebuild the solution.

Comment: Thought it might be something simple. Thank you :)